# Issuer label on QR code for 2FA not showing correct value

Tags: two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator, totp, authenticator, speakeasy

I am using speakeasy library and qrcode library, to generate an otpauth URL and then transforming it into a QR code, so this can be scanned by an authenticator app for 2FA on my website.

I want the authenticator apps to show my website in the following format:

> Test Company (<-- the name of my website)
>
> test@fakemail.com (<-- the email of the user)

My code to generate the url is:

```
let url = speakeasy.otpauthURL({ secret: secret.base32, label: userEmail, issuer: 'Test Company', encoding: 'base32' })
```

This generates a URL like so:

> otpauth://totp/test@fakemail.com?secret=ENTEWOKSHQRXQ4CYGBREYWDVFRTGYVRXNF2FWSBRKE7SUOJZGY4Q&issuer=Test%20Company

And then I transform it to a QR code like so:

```
let qrImageUrl = await qrcode.toDataURL(url)
```

I now try to set up 2FA with my user with email address "test@fakemail.com". It seems it takes the first part of the email domain as the issuer.
The result in Microsoft Authenticator app looks like this:

> fakemail
>
> test@fakemail.com

But when I scan this exact same code in Google Authenticator app, it shows me (on one line):

> Test Company (test@fakemail.com)

When changing the code to contain a colon like so:

```
let url = speakeasy.otpauthURL({ secret: secret.ascii, label: `Test Company:${userEmail}` })
```

In microsoft authenticator app it will now show perfectly like so:

> Test Company
>
> test@fakemail.com

But in Google authenticator app, it shows in one line with the semi colon literally in there:

> Test Company:test@fakemail.com

What is the correct approach to have every single authenticator app in the exact same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pass all the possibilities combined into the same request.
Normally the application itself will use the most applicable variables and will show accordingly in the specific app.

```
let url = speakeasy.otpauthURL({ secret: secret.base32, label: `Test Company:${userEmail}`, issuer: 'Test Company', encoding: 'base32' })
```